# Google Map Echo Out Latitude. & Longitude of Multiple Markers On Page.

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map that when you click the map it will place a marker on the map and print out or echo out to the html the latitude and longitude and address. Here is what I want to do I want to echo out the latitude and longitude and address every time a new markers is added but leave the previous marker on the page to be seen. I am trying to do it with a for loop. I got it to work but the alert window just keeps saying object Object instead of echoing out the latitude and longitude and address of the new marker. Here is my code.

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var poly;
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infowindow = null;
    var path = new google.maps.MVCArray;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    function geocodePosition(pos) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
      }, function(responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
          updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
        } else {
          updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
        }
      });
    }

    function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
      document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
        latLng.lat(),
        latLng.lng()
      ].join(', ');

    }

    function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
      document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
    }

    function initialize() {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.2844783, -84.3558012);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapCanvas"), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: latLng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        });

        poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#5555FF'
        });
        poly.setMap(map);
        poly.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([path]));

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', addPoint);

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({   content: "holding..."
    });
    }

    var markers=[];
            for (var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){

     function addPoint(event) {
        path.insertAt(path.length, event.latLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
        }); 
            markers.push(marker);
            marker.setTitle("#" + path.length);

        // Add dragging event listeners.

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
            updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
            updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
            updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.setMap(null);
            for (var i = 0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; ++i);
                markers.splice(i, 1);
            path.removeAt(i);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            for (var i = 0, I = markers.length; i < I && markers[i] != marker; ++i);
                path.setAt(i, marker.getPosition());
        });

        updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
        geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());

        alert(markers.join("\n"));
     }

    }
    // Onload handler to fire off the app.
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
      <style>
      #mapCanvas {
        width: 700px;
        height: 600px;
        float: left;
      }
      #infoPanel {
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      #infoPanel div {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
      }
    </style>

      <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
      <div id="infoPanel">
        <b>Marker status:</b>
        <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
        <b>Current position:</b>
        <div id="info"></div>
        <b>Closest matching address:</b>
        <div id="address"></div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to debug, try using console.log instead. In most browsers that support debugging utilities it will provide you with a lot more detail. If you don't know what I mean by that, just search for debugging tools for whatever browser you're working with. When you try to call "join" on the markers variable, toString is being invoked or each element in the array before they are joined by "\n". The default toString() on most complex objects is pretty unhelpful. Replace the alert with something like this:

```
console.log(markers);
```

If you're not trying to debug I'd look at a different way of presenting the information than in an alert box.